# I can't transform geometries to a projection defined in proj4.defs in openlayers 5.3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-5, proj4js

I have a Node mapping application that uses openlayers V5.3.0. When I try to transform geometries from EPSG:4326 to a projection defined using proj4.defs I get this error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCode' of null

If I change openLayers to version 4.6.4 the code to transform the geometries works.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

The following HTML demonstrates the problem.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
    <title>Projection Test</title>

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.4/ol-debug.js"></script> -->

    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>


    <script>proj4.defs("EPSG:28355","+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");</script>

     <script>

         $(document).ready(function() {
             let gJSONOpts = {
                 dataProjection: "EPSG:3857",
                 featureProjection: "EPSG:28355"
             };

             let jsonPt = {
                 "type": "Feature",
                 "id": "GEO_BRM_STOPS.fid--79f50be5_16adc4d0ce7_6a6b",
                 "geometry": {
                     "type": "Point",
                     "coordinates": [16154413.50099648, -4988654.4460995]
                 },
                 "geometry_name": "OBJ"
             };

             let feature = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeature(jsonPt.geometry, gJSONOpts);
             let tg = feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:28355', "EPSG:4326");
             let out = 'Projected Coordinates: ' + tg.getCoordinates()[0] + ', ' +tg.getCoordinates()[1];

             $("#mapvwr").html(out);

         });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapvwr">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Paste the above into an html file and show it in the browser.

Uncomment this line:

```
 <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/openlayers/4.6.4/ol-debug.js"></script> -->
```

and comment out the following line:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
```

To see the correct result:

```
Projected Coordinates: 145.11756553931886, -40.83921285742692
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.
I need to add this as a script `ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);` after I have defined the projection.

Comment: can you add source code where you add proj4 ?

Comment: Yes you could write any valid JavaScript code there

Comment: what is the value of proj4

Comment: i am trying to transform projection 32640 to 3857 but same error getting getCode undefined. So i want to know parameter of ol.proj.proj4.register()

Comment: proj4.defs("EPSG:28355","+proj=utm +zone=55 +south +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs");

Comment: register is not available in ol@4.6.5

Comment: It was new in version 5.3.0. You should consider upgrading to a new version of openlayers